# Edit DWG file with autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any way I can allow my user to edit DWG files using Autodesk Forge?
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/
I was able to integrate this viewer to view my models. Is there any way I can edit them?
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/edit2d-setup/
Maybe using this 2d tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autodesk Platform Service Viewer,former Forge Viewer, doesn't have funtionality to edit source file.

For that pouperse, you need to use Desing Automation API. Please note that Design Automation API is designed for batch process, not for real time modification.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/